# JavaScript: Invalid destructuring target

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

Here is the code:

```
 function BinarySearchNode(key) {
     let node = {};
     node.key = key;
     node.lft = null;
     node.rgt = null;

     node.log = () => {
         console.log(node.key);
     }

     node.get_node_with_parent = (key) => {
         let parent = null;

         while (this) {
             if (key == this.key) {
                 return [this, parent];
             }

             if (key < this.key) {
                 [this, parent] = [this.lft, this];
             } else {
                 [this, parent] = [this.rgt, this];
             }
         }

         return [null, parent];
     }

     return node;
 }
```

My Firefox is `44.0` and it throws a `SyntaxError` for these lines:

```
if (key < this.key) {
    [this, parent] = [this.lft, this];
} else {
```

I tried to understand what exactly is wrong here by reading [this blogpost](http://www.2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html) and [the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Unfortuntely, I am still missing it :(

Comment: Wouldn't that mean you're trying to assign the object out from under itself?

Comment: @DaveNewton no idea to be honest. Currently my understanding is that `this` is like `self` in python: just a reference (a name, a pointer) for the object. So, if I reassign it to another object, I am fine. Maybe not though.

Comment: Not so much. It *is* a reference to an object, but the object is itself. What would it mean to set yourself to something different? Oft-used movie plot, not so hot in code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) is not a variable, but a keyword and cannot be assigned to. Use a variable instead:

```
node.get_node_with_parent = function(key) {
    let parent = null;
    let cur = this; // if you use an arrow function, you'll need `node` instead of `this`
    while (cur) {
        if (key == cur.key) {
            return [cur, parent];
        }
        if (key < cur.key) {
            [cur, parent] = [cur.lft, cur];
        } else {
            [cur, parent] = [cur.rgt, cur];
        }
    }
    return [null, parent];
}
```

Comment: thanks, I see your comment about `node` and `this`, I am currently banging my head a little because of this scoping/closure/no idea what it is properly called.

Comment: If you use `this` in an arrow function, it won't refer to the object the function (method) is invoked on, but to the same `this` as its parent scope - in your case, the `this` of `BinarySearchNode`. If it was a constructor (and invoked with `new`), this would make sense, but currently it's just a factory function and you'll want to refer to `node` through closure.